# Getting an array of navigation controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

In my app I would like to know the current view controller when my app goes in the background.

how is this possible to do in the storyboard since there is no navigation controller reference in app delegate?

Answer (score 2):

If your storyboard's root view is a navigation controller, you can likely access the view controller stack using the following in your app delegate:

`((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController).viewControllers`

You could then access the -[NSArray lastObject] method to get the view controller on the top of the stack.

Comment: how to add one particular view controller on top if for example in using xib we can write  [(LoginVC *)navigate.topViewController toAddView];
what we will write in case of storyboard ?

Comment: You'd create a view controller using `–[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]` to create the view controller from your storyboard, then use `-[UINavigationController pushViewController: animated:]` to get it onto the navigation stack.

By the looks of it though, toAddView may return the view controller you want to add. In that case you'd use that as the first parameter in the `pushViewController:animated:` method.

Comment: What i like to trying to do is to find the current view controller in app delegate then to call a particular method of that view controller.how to call that method in case of xib i can call using this  [(LoginVC *)navigate.topViewController toAddView]; but here no reference to navigation.

Comment: The navigation controller is returned as a part of my initial answer, `(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController` where self is your app delegate.